# In MIPS assembly , does malloc call allocate the memory space in stack area?

Tags: stack, malloc, mips

As I know, heaps such as malloc is stored in dynamic data. But is it right to say
that malloc function call may allocate the memory space in stack area?

Answer (score 1):

`malloc` is not a feature of MARS or QtSpim.

There is a system call, #9, that mimics *nix `sbrk`, to allocate additional address space to the simulated process.  It returns to you the next address available past the global data (and past any prior `sbrk`'s).  (However, it only allocates, and does not return memory the way a proper `sbrk` would do given a negative value.)  Another name for this area of memory is heap / heap memory.

It does not allocate stack space as that is in substantially higher in the address space.  On these simulators, the stack is limited to about 4MB, and the memory returned by `sbrk` does not reach anywhere near into that 4MB.

Heap memory is useful since a heap allocated memory will survive a function call — a function can return data in the heap but cannot return newly allocated data in the stack, since, by definition, a function that allocates stack space must release that exact same amount when it leaves.

Stack space is allocated simply by decrementing the stack pointer (and released by incrementing the stack pointer).  By convention, all functions & subroutines agree to leave existing stack memory alone and allocate new stack memory if they want it, though they also must release it before returning to their caller.  When those restrictions do not meet requirements, heap memory is a good choice.  Global data is also an option for memory that survives a function call, though that can lead to problems with multithreading (and potentially with recursion).

Comment: From what I understand (and I'm not an expert), `malloc` will use the operating system to search the heap for the requested range of memory that isn't in use (how the OS decides what memory is "in use," I have no idea), and if successful, returns a pointer to that memory. Otherwise, you get a null pointer back. Technically, the heap and the stack don't really exist, there's just a (usually contiguous) pool of RAM, and the stack pointer starts at the top of that and the heap at the bottom.

Comment: `mallioc` is a C Library function, the OS in not involved except as the underlying source of larger memory blocks.  `malloc` may consult a free list first, then spare space from larger blocks (probably by them being on the free list), then asks the OS as needed.  The free list is added to by `free`, another C Lib function.  Other languages can and might manage memory without these C Lib functions.  @puppydrum64

Comment: I might be confused with MS-DOS which had some sort of method to find some free space